# How to Implement Cloudinary Upload Widget in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, upload, cloudinary

I'm trying to use the Cloudinary Upload Widget in Angular. I followed to example code provided by cloudinary but it doesn't seem to work. It looks like I'm missing an import or a package to get access to the function `cloudinary.createUploadWidget`
I've installed and imported:

```
import { CloudinaryModule } from '@cloudinary/ng';
```

In app.module.ts. and I have added

```
<script
  src="https://upload-widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js"
  type="text/javascript"
></script>
```

in the index.html file.

but I still get the Cannot find name 'cloudinary' error in my component.
What import am I missing to get access to 'cloudinary' in my angular component. The cloudinary documentation doesn't clarifies it and in their Sandbox Example they have the same error.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myWidget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget( /// this is where the error occurs
      {
        cloudName: this.cloudName,
        uploadPreset: this.uploadPreset
     
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (!error && result && result.event === "success") {
          console.log("Done! Here is the image info: ", result.info);
          document
            .getElementById("uploadedimage")
            .setAttribute("src", result.info.secure_url);
        }
      }
    );
```

Does anybody had any luck making the cloudinary upload widget work in angular?
Any insight of what I'm missing is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following these steps:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/angular_quick_start

Answer (score 0):

I had the same,
I found the solution here
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cloudinary-angular-media-library-ofmex?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

It seems that adding **(window as any)** before cloudinary solves the problem.

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.myWidget = (window as any).cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
  {
    cloudName: this.cloudName,
    uploadPreset: this.uploadPreset
 
  },
  (error, result) => {
    if (!error && result && result.event === "success") {
      console.log("Done! Here is the image info: ", result.info);
      document
        .getElementById("uploadedimage")
        .setAttribute("src", result.info.secure_url);
    }
  }
);
```

Hope that will help.